# Stackdriver Dashboards eating all our memory

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

I often have to build Stackdriver dashboards. The browser tab of an ordinary dashboard with six charts clocks in at **1.8 GB (!)** in Google Chrome Task Manager.

This would normally be a question for the product team, but next to its sluggish behaviour (e.g. compared to Grafana dashboards) and it crippling machines, this hasn't changed since its initial introduction to GCP years ago.

So my question: **How to reduce the load on project members' workstations?** Via dashboard design, a specific way of using the dashboards, or maybe browser plugins?

Comment: not sure if you will get a desired answer, stackdriver is just very very memory hungry and there's not much you can do :/

Comment: It not only used all the CPU but also used GPU so hard my macOS started crashing in few seconds with GPU panic until my Macbook became totally unusable. Had to buy a new one. When I asked about it in their Slack community one guy was intentionally flooding the channel to make devs not see my issue. When I told him that his behaviour is idiotic the Google staff threatened to ban me. So their software burned my Macbook and I was disallowed to ask to resolve the issue. Now this question will be closed and deleted because "not clear what you are asking", "no snippet of code provided", etc.